# Nmap enum-shares not working

Tags: nmap, network-shares

I am trying to list a shared folder I have on the desktop of a virtual machine. with these commands:

nmap -sU -sS --script smb-enum-shares.nse -p U:137,T:139 10.10.10.115

nmap --script smb-enum-shares.nse -p445 10.10.10.115

The combined output is :

```
Nmap scan report for 10.10.10.115
Host is up (0.00s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
137/udp open  netbios-ns
MAC Address: 08:00:27:31:DB:FC (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)
```

This is not the output I am supposed to get referring to this : https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-enum-shares.html

Why is it not listing the shared folder on the desktop ? I have set maximum permission to everyone for the folder.

Thank you !

Guillaume

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bug in nmap https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/704

You can try `-d` flag to run nmap in debug mode. I see the "SMB: Login as \guest failed (NT_STATUS_ACCOUNT_DISABLED)" error. But other utilites (e.g. softperfect network scanner) works fine without specific permisions on remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation: [smb-enum-shares](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-enum-shares.html). Use function *add_account* in *smbauth* module